# Script that formats a drive in a very specific way

Tags: partitioning, scripts, filesystem

I want to format a drive using a script in Ubuntu.

**The required specs are:**

- Partition table: *Master Boot Record*
- Partition Type: *Linux*
- File System: *Ext2*

[image: Screenshot of the desired result.]

My current problems:

```
sudo parted mklablel msdos
```

*Doesn't change the Partition type to "Linux"*

```
sudo mkfs.ext2
```

*Doesn't work without existing filesystem*

So how can I achieve my specs?

Answer (score 2):

First you are missing the block device for the commands to work on. In your case that seems like being */dev/sdc*.
The `parted mklabel` command does not create a partition but puts a disklabel on the disk and is needed to partition the disk.
The next step would be to create a partition on the labeled disk and afterwards create a filesystem within that partition. `mkfs.ext2` will create a filesystem.

So the single steps would be as follows. Be carefull in executing and be sure to pick the right blockdevice */dev/sdx*, otherwise you will loose data.

First, clean the disk from preexisting things.

```
root@localhost:~# wipefs -a /dev/sdc
```

Then create the disklabel and the partition.

```
root@localhost:~# parted /dev/sdc mklabel msdos
root@localhost:~# parted /dev/sdc mkpart pri 1MiB 100%
```

Finally create a filesystem within the partition.

```
root@localhost:~# mkfs.ext2 -F /dev/sdc1
```

If you are not logged in as `root` you have to prepend each command with `sudo`. Also consider using `gpt` as disklabel instead of `msdos` as you can create larger and more partitions with `gpt`.
You also might want to choose `ext4` as filesystem instead of `ext2`, but you also might have reasons for `ext2`.

Comment: I find my devices can change based on whether flash drive is plugged in on reboot or not. That is why they now use UUIDs or labels as preferred way to refer to a drive. If you script it for sdc and drive is not sdc, you may destroy data on another drive.

Comment: That is true, but a label and UUID for e.g. mounting is only available after creating a filesystem. If start from the ground labeling, partitioning a disk and creating a filesystem you have to refer to your block devices which is `/dev/sd*` or any device you can find in `/dev/disk/by-*`. Nevertheless, when it comes to creating a partition you have to identify the blockdevice the disk is reflected by.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with `gparted`

If you don't have installed:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gparted`

1. Launch GParted
2. Select the drive in top right (make sure to select external drive!)
3. Right Click on the partition
4. Select Format to -> ext2
5. Click Edit -> Apply all operations

Comment: The question asks for a scriptable solution, not a GUI way.